# Problem in code for inserting the Figures and Tables in top of next page

Tags: floats, code

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to influence the position of float environments like figure and table in LaTeX?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39017/how-to-influence-the-position-of-float-environments-like-figure-and-table-in-lat)

How I can set up the figure and tables to capture them in the next page. I have a problem in inserting the figure. I have referenced the figure but it has appeared before the specified place. I would like to revise the code in a way that figures appear in a next top part of page.

Code:

```
\begin{figure}
    \centering
        \includegraphics[width=0.9\textwidth]{C:/Thesis/Latex/thesis_1(1)/Figures/studyArea.jpg}
        \rule{35em}{0.3pt}
    \caption{The Grand St. Bernard wireless sensor network deployment (a) the coordinates of nodes according to the Swiss coordinate system (b) the distribution of the nodes in the study site \citep{r33}}
    \label{fig:study area}
\end{figure}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specific to your problem - placing a float at the top of the next page - the [`afterpage` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/afterpage) could be of help:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{afterpage,float,lipsum,graphicx}% http://ctan.org/pkg/{afterpage,float,lipsum,graphicx}
\begin{document}
See Figure~\ref{fig:label}. \lipsum[1-4]
\afterpage{%
  \begin{figure}[H]
    \centering
    \includegraphics[height=20pt,width=0.9\textwidth]{example-image-a}
    \caption{This is a caption}
    \label{fig:label}
  \end{figure}
}
\lipsum[5-10]
\end{document}
```

[`float`](http://ctan.org/pkg/float) provides the `[H]` float specifier. However, you might just as well have used a `minipage` environment and (say) [`caption`](http://ctan.org/pkg/caption)'s `\captionof{figure}{...}` for the caption.

Answer (score 3):

Floats (figures and tables) can be forced to appear based on a set of parameters in the `\begin{} ... \end{}` float object. The syntax is `\begin{figure}[x]` where `x` can be `h` for placing "here"; `t` at the top of the (possibly curent) page; `b` at the bottom of the page; `!` overrides all good parameter settings and forces an even harder "here". if you use the package float you also have `H` which is similar to `!h`. In addition there is a package `placeins` that provides a command `\FloatBarrier` which prevents floats from behin set after the command.